# joomla chronoform saving data

Tags: forms, joomla, chronoforms

I have a problem  with chronoform.
I created my form and everything. but when people input data, sometimes it doesn't get saved, sometimes the data look strange (encrypted?), but when it's me trying the form, it always works!

here an example of the strange data:

> REGISTRATION DATE 2011-02-24 - 08:24:14
>
> NAME xjvcZiqVZOf
>
> SURNAME mbYCUldaGCfE
>
> CHARGE CDOWWXMGA
>
> CARD FdaYQzKjvJRjDdHiN
>
> PHONE fUCjEIKBOQgBdtRUcdS
>
> EMAIL qwrelb@gzblvr.com
>
> HOW DID YOU GET TO KNOW THE LABMOND? w2yCfW iuykmqzzrasu,[url=http://stxpmgksgwqu.com/]stxpmgksgwqu[/url], [link=http://qdchzokvtmyk.com/]qdchzokvtmyk[/link], http://fxbqxghstmyn.com/
>
> LABMOND LEVEL 2Â° Livello
>
> LOCAL OFFICE Campobasso

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the built in captch or ReCaptcha, I bet these submissions are bots.

Comment: yes, I spoke with the developer of the component, and he was of the same opinion. I was just curious about why the spammers would do something like this? What is their aim? and how were they able to bypass the submit button (if you notice labmond level it has a non unicode formatting, the developer told me that it's like this because the spammer override the normal submission)?

Comment: It's hard to say what the spammers are trying to accomplish, it may just be the first part of a multistep attack. Stopping the submission of course is definitely the way to go.